# Group by multiple columns creating new column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dateframe of two columns ['company'] which is a string and ['publication_datetime'] which is a datetime.

I want to group by company and the publication_**date** , adding a new column with the maximum publication_**datetime** for each record.

so far i have tried:

```
issuers = news[['company','publication_datetime']]
issuers['publication_date'] = issuers['publication_datetime'].dt.date
issuers['publication_datetime_max'] = issuers.groupby(['company','publication_date'], as_index=False)['publication_datetime'].max()
```

my group by does not appear to work.

i get the following error

```
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `transform()` method to cast the result in the original dimension of the dataframe.

```
issuers['max'] = issuers.groupby(['company', 'publication_date'])['publication_datetime'].transform('max')
```

The result of your `groupby()` before was returning a multi-indexed group object, which is why it's complaining about 3 values (first group, second group, and then values). But even if you just returned the values, it's combining like groups together, so you'll have fewer values than needed.

The `transform()` method returns the group results for each row of the dataframe in a way that makes it easy to create a new column. The returned values are an indexed `Series` with the indices being the original ones from the `issuers` dataframe.

Hope this helps! Documentation for transform [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html)

Answer (score 0):

The thing is by doing what you are doing you are trying to set a `DataFrame` to a column value. 
Doing the following will get extract only the values without the two indexe columns:

```
issuers['publication_datetime_max'] = issuers.groupby(['company','publication_date'], as_index=False)['publication_datetime'].max().tolist()
```

Hope this help !